# PHP - Location inside multiple polygons

Tags: php, math, geometry, polygon

How can i turn this in to supporting more polygons than just this one? I think of something with arrays but I’m lost this code works with one polygon but just can’t get any further this is what I got:

I would like it to check if the point is in polygon A or B or C and so on depending on how many polygons I got right now it only checking if point is inside polygon A.

```
class Point {
    public $lat;
    public $long;
    function Point($lat, $long) {
        $this->lat = $lat;
        $this->long = $long;
    }
}

//the Point in Polygon function
function pointInPolygon($p, $polygon) {
    //if you operates with (hundred)thousands of points
    set_time_limit(60);
    $c = 0;
    $p1 = $polygon[0];
    $n = count($polygon);

    for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++) {
        $p2 = $polygon[$i % $n];
        if ($p->long > min($p1->long, $p2->long)
            && $p->long <= max($p1->long, $p2->long)
            && $p->lat <= max($p1->lat, $p2->lat)
            && $p1->long != $p2->long) {
                $xinters = ($p->long - $p1->long) * ($p2->lat - $p1->lat) / ($p2->long - $p1->long) + $p1->lat;
                if ($p1->lat == $p2->lat || $p->lat <= $xinters) {
                    $c++;
                }
        }
        $p1 = $p2;
    }
    // if the number of edges we passed through is even, then it's not in the poly.
    return $c%2!=0;
}

$polygon = array(
    new Point(54.992883, -9.860767),
    new Point(54.992775, -9.860289),
    new Point(54.992236,- 9.861030),
    new Point(54.992473, -9.862007)
);
```

Comment: Sure, you're using PHP, but the problem you're asking about is not a PHP programming problem: tag your post with the tags that match your problem. Just `php` is definitely not going to get you the geometry algorithm folks looking at it =) (That said, if the only thing you're confused about is "how do I check more than one polygon" the answer is to use an array. Stick all your polygons you need to test in an array, and then foreach your way to success).

Comment: It's not clear exactly what outcome you want. Do you mean you want to be able to pass more than one item into the `pointInPolygon` function and get multiple results? Or something else? Please be specific about what you're trying to achieve. "supporting more polygons" is a bit vague and doesn't really give us a definite goal.

Comment: This point is only looking into one polygon but I would like it to check multiple polygons like to se if user is In area 1 or 2 or 3 or 5 … and so on

Comment: So what exactly happens when you run the code right now? What result did you get? And what result did you expect instead? Also please show you how call the function currently - we don't know what you're passing in for the `$p` variable.

Comment: As a basic observation, is `for ($i=1; $i<=$n; $i++) {` a logic error? Or did you intend to ignore the first item in the $polygon array when you loop? Although actually I think you'll end up looping them all because of `$polygon[$i % $n]`. Again is that deliberate, to change the order they are processed, or just a workaround for not knowing to start the loop at 0 in the conventional way? Just asking because you haven't explained your algorithm at all, so we're going to poke holes in any tiny bits we can see, unless you explain the logic.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough yet. Please clarify whether you need a boolean result if there is at least **one** polygon containing the the point or a **list of all (intersecting) polygons** containing the dot.
Btw. as @ADyson remarked, your algorithm counting from 1 to count of vertices on a zero-based array and performing a modulo is not the most elegant way. There are better alternatives to implement the Jordan's Polygon Test.